# Materialized View Oracle: How to use sysdate in clause where with FAST ON COMMIT Option

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, database-administration

I am trying to create a Materialized view on Oracle (version 19c) with the code snippet below:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON SOURCE_TABLE;

CREATE materialized VIEW VIEW_SOURCE_TABLE_DMINUS1 
  REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT 
AS
SELECT fild1, fild2,fild3,Timestamp 
  FROM SED_MQ_ARCHIVES
 WHERE field1 = 'DATA1' 
   AND field2 = 'DATA2' 
   and field3 = 'DATA3' 
   and trunc(Timestamp) >= trunc(SYSATE)-1;
```

I am trying to filter all records dated from day-1(last 48h) from a big table.

when executing the code, I got the below issue:

> 12054. 00000 -  "cannot set the ON COMMIT refresh attribute for the materialized view"
>        *Cause:    The materialized view did not satisfy conditions for refresh at
>        commit time.
>        *Action:   Specify only valid options.

Seems issue is related to the 'sysdate' function which is not compatible with 'REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT' option. Is there a workaround for this kind of use case?

Comment: You can't do an `on commit` refresh of a materialized view with a non-deterministic function.  You could have the MV refresh on a schedule instead.  But it's not obvious that a materialized view is the right approach here-- if you're just filtering data, it would seem highly likely that you just want an index on (`field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `trunc(timestamp)`) (or just `timestamp` and get rid of the `trunc` in the query since it's not adding anything).

Comment: Possible you can also check the *partitioning* option - here a *daily* partitioning on the `timestamp` column.

Comment: thanks for quick reply! We want to use MV as the source table contains millions records(thre is already index set up for this table) and there is process requiring this data(D-1) which is running approximatively every 5 min, so as an optimization, instead quering on the source table, we thought that using MV is more suitable for this use case as it updates only new records, the scope(number of record) should be globally the same on the MV.

Comment: If you have a table with *inserts* only, this is one more go to the *partitioning*. Queries with a predicate `timestamp >= trunc(SYSATE)-1` will be *pruned* to the last two partitions only.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have Partionning option in our database.

Comment: Is the base table a table or a view? If it is a table then most likely an index will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

One (somewhat convoluted) workaround might be to create a second table that contains only the date you need for the predicate:

```
create materialized view yesterday as
select trunc(sysdate - 1) as the_date from dual;
```

then use that in your mview as:

```
...
and Timestamp >= ( select the_date from yesterday )
```

You'll need a scheduler job to keep the new mview up to date at midnight and a full refresh of your mview once that's done to get rid of the old values that are no longer valid.

(I haven't actually tried or verified this; it's just an idea.)

Comment: after deep searchs, this is the solution I will implement. thanks